# conversion to MB does not work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the below code (which goes through the C: drive and gets file info data) and want to convert the length to a "respectable" number - i.e MB. The problem is that the line below does not do anything to the code. Any help would be appreciated:

Line is: strlength = strlength * (1024 / 1024)

Private Sub btnclick_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnclick.Click

```
    Dim strFilesinfo As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim strlength As Double = 0
    Dim strname As String = ""

    For Each strFiles As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("c:\")

        strFilesinfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(strFiles)

        strlength = strFilesinfo.Length
        strname = strFilesinfo.Name

        strlength = strlength * (1024 / 1024)
        lstData.Items.Add(strname & " " & strlength)

    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: strlength = strlength * (1024 / 1024)? I think 1024 / 1024 will return 1 and it will only return the value of strlength.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dividing by 1:

```
strlength = strlength * (1024 / 1024)
```

The parenthesis makes 1024 divided by 1024 happen first which equals 1.

Should be

```
strlength = strlength / 1024 / 1024
```